# DataGrid pagination not aligning to the right in container with dir="rtl"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, position

I'm trying to create a DataGrid with pagination using Material-UI in a container with dir="rtl". I've customized the pagination component to be aligned to the right side of the container, but it's not working as expected.

Here's a example In [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-rgb-6gvrfi?file=/demo.js)

I've defined Box dir="rtl". when I run the code, the pagination component is aligned to the left side of the container.

How can I make the pagination component appear on the right side of the container, while still using dir="rtl"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your `CustomPagination` component to align it to the right side.

In your codesandbox, I just added  `style={{ display: "flex", width: "100%" }}>` in the `<div>` and `sx={{ ml: "auto" }}` in the `<Pagination>` to make it work.

```
 function CustomPagination() {
 const apiRef = useGridApiContext();
 const page = useGridSelector(apiRef, gridPageSelector);
 const pageCount = useGridSelector(apiRef, gridPageCountSelector);

   return (
       <div dir="ltr" style={{ display: "flex", width: "100%" }}>
          <Pagination
            color="primary"
            count={pageCount}
            page={page + 1}
            onChange={(event, value) => apiRef.current.setPage(value - 1)}
            sx={{ ml: "auto" }}
          />
       </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Can you please tell me how did you know what needs to be added?

Because I want to understand it myself without asking here, and I can spend half my day just trying to positioning a button

Comment: I just check the Elements and CSS in Chrome dev tool to see what it stopping it for aligning it to right side and add the missing CSS in right place. And I'm working on a MUI project from last two years, So I have faced these problems in the past already.